# Angular 5 - forms input - trigger event when clicking on suggested values

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, input, event-handling

I want to handle the click event when clicking on suggested values down the input `(click)="doSomething()"` doesnt fire it.

- At the end I want that typing smth in the input and clicking on these suggested values fire an event. For visualization a picture:
  [image]

My source code so far:

```
<input type="text"[(ngModel)]="filterModel.selectedClanNameOrClanTag"
                   class="form-control" minlength="3"
                   placeholder="Enter clan id or name..."
                   name="clanNameOrClanTag" required
                  (keyup)="formChange(clanForm.value)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ngModelChange`

```
<input type="text"[(ngModel)]="filterModel.selectedClanNameOrClanTag"
                   class="form-control" minlength="3"
                   placeholder="Enter clan id or name..."
                   name="clanNameOrClanTag" required
                   (ngModelChange)="YourFunct()"
                  (keyup)="formChange(clanForm.value)">
```

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in stackblitz